# usage of `content=''` in pseudo elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I started learning CSS form w3school.com ,and the problem I found in myself was that I couldn't understand `content=''` usage.
for example here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_styles

so can someone explain how to use it? and when should I?
example above is this:(this example is one of CSS examples in responsice web design section)

````
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

html {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #9933cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #0099cc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 menu">
    <ul>
      <li>The Flight</li>
      <li>The City</li>
      <li>The Island</li>
      <li>The Food</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-9">
    <h1>The City</h1>
    <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content property, used with ::before ::after pseudo elements, is literally there to insert content that isn't there. Example:

> `.email::before { content: "email address:"; }`
>
> `<div class=email>jo@email.com</div>`

would render the following:

> `email address: jo@email.com`

The code you have shows `content:""` which  part of the code commonly used for a clearfix hack. Basically elements after a floating element will flow around it. The following code will stop that from happening.

```
> `.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}`
```

Delete the code and see what happens to the content.
This page of W3Schools talks about it:
[Clearfix](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp)

CSS-Tricks has more info about content property
[All about the CSS Content property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/)

Comment: thank you ,also i couldnt find anything about it thank you for links

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)